# angular 4 dateFormat condition check

Tags: angular

Here in `[locale]="language"` tag different languages are coming like fr,en...

I want to check **if language='fr' then dateFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"** and **if language='en' then dateFormat="YYYY/MM/DD"** and so on. ho can i **check using angular 4 in dateFormat tag??**

I have tried this things but not working.

```
<owl-date-time id="emailDateTime" [placeHolder]="'Date of the first export'" [locale]="language"  [disabled]="isNowOnly" [hideClearButton]="isNowOnly" dateFormat="language=='fr'?MM/DD/YYYY:DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="moment" [min]="minDate" [ngClass]="['form-control', dateErrorMessage != '' ? 'reporting-form-error-border': '',isNowOnly?'disabled':'']" [inputStyleClass]="isNowOnly?'disabled':''" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></owl-date-time>


<owl-date-time id="emailDateTime" [placeHolder]="'Date of the first export'" [locale]="language"  [disabled]="isNowOnly" [hideClearButton]="isNowOnly" dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="moment" [min]="minDate" [ngClass]="['form-control', dateErrorMessage != '' ? 'reporting-form-error-border': '',isNowOnly?'disabled':'']" [inputStyleClass]="isNowOnly?'disabled':''" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></owl-date-time>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

### html

```
<owl-date-time [dateFormat]="getDateFormat(language)"></owl-date-time>
```

### ts

```
getDateFormat(lang) {
   if (lang === 'fr') {
      return 'MM/DD/YYYY';
   } else {
      return 'YYYY/MM/DD';
   }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to check the condition in dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" ?

Comment: You can try ternary operator like [dateFormat]="language=='fr'?'MM/DD/YYYY':'YYYY/MM/DD'"

Comment: Function calling way is working for you? Because I am haven't check for that